# I want to put tabbar on second view

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

Usally ,tabbar always displays buttom.

like this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
 }
```

but I want to diplay tabbar on second view (only).

1-2 is connected by navicontroller

2 is  @interface TableViewController :UITableViewController

how??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better to add the tab bar controller programmatically in secondviewcontroller viewdidload

Comment: first thank you for answer me. I try yours now .but how? because second view is @interface TableViewController :UITableViewController so - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    
    self.navigationItem.title=mSearchKey;   
    NewsListTabbar =[[UITabBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 361, 320, 59)]; but don't work. why?

Comment: or else do like this.Add tabbarcontroller in the app delegate.First you need to hide it and then you have show the tab bar.